# Have I heard that toast before?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-beyond, the-wrath-of-khan, the-voyage-home

[image]

In Star Trek Beyond, a few days before the anniversary of Captain Kirk's father's death, he and Dr. McCoy have a sip of 30 year old scotch taken from Chekov's locker. Bones pours a finger into 3 glasses. I assume the third glass is to remember George Kirk. Then he makes a toast: **"Here's to perfect eyesight and a full head of hair."** Wha?!

[image]

In TOS: the Corbomite Maneuver Bones serves Captain Kirk something that might be scotch. Perhaps he was going to make a toast but Yeoman Rand interrupts their conversation with a salad - of all things. There are other countless times when they have a drink, but a lot of people draw a parallel to the Romulan Ale they share in The Wrath of Khan.

[image]

Whatever the time, I don't remember Bones ever making a toast. Is this a reference to some previous toast I can't remember? Is this a nod to the glasses Kirk had in Star Trek IV? Is it a joke about Shatner's toupee? Anyone have any insight?

Comment: "a nod to the glasses Kirk had in Star Trek IV"--those glasses were a birthday present McCoy gave Kirk in the scene from the beginning of Wrath of Khan that you posted the screenshot from, and in that scene the fact that Kirk *didn't* have good eyesight anymore was part of a theme the movie was setting up about him feeling like he was getting old. So the toast in Star Trek Beyond was probably a sort of ironic reference that was meant to contrast with that scene, although I don't know of any definite confirmation of this from anyone involved with the movie.

Comment: Spielberg threatened to sue for "Here's to swimmin' with bow-legged women."  :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pure supposition, but the toast was almost certainly a playful jab at both the actor (William Shatner) and the character he portrayed (James Kirk)

## Perfect Eyesight

Kirk was known to be allergic to [Retinax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Retinax_V), a drug which would have improved his eyesight. He was forced to rely on a set of antique reading glasses for fine work.

[image]

### Head of hair

William Shatner has faced some merriment and criticism over the years for the poor quality of his wigs, designed to cover up extensive baldness.

[image]

Comment: Is that true? Is Shatner really bald? How do we know that?

Comment: @JerryNixon-TOS - Discussed extensively (and obsessively) [here](http://shatnerstoupee.blogspot.co.uk/)